# How to make Xfce terminal run a command when it starts?

Tags: xfce4-terminal

I want the Xfce terminal to run a command when it is turned on, for example print a welcome message or some system stats. I want this message to be printed only on the Xfce terminal emulator when it starts, not on some other terminal emulators. Can I achieve this effect by modifying the file `terminalrc`? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I added this code to the `.bashrc` file.

```
if [ $COLORTERM == "xfce4-terminal" ]
then
   echo "Welcome to the Xfce4 Terminal"
fi
```

Comment: Why you used `$COLORTERM`? I think that could be sufficient write `if [ "xfce4-terminal" ]`

Answer (score 4):

If you absolutely want to do this, I see two approaches:

1) Make a bash (or whatever shell you use) profile script that gets the parent `PID` to see if it is running under `xfce4-terminal`, and, if so, prints your message.

2) Something like this (note you may have to re-run it after OS upgrades, or it may even befuddle your package manager into not working properly anymore):

```
W="$(which xfce4-terminal)"
sudo cp "$W" "$W".orig
sudo tee "$W" <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec ${W}.orig -e 'sh -c "echo this is xfce4-terminal ... ; bash"'
EOF
sudo chmod a+x "$W"
```

Comment: That is one ugly hack.  I haven't tried it but I suppose it probably works.  Your first choice would probably be nicer.